# How do I improve and isolate from mains ground my Tesla coil control circuit?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, mosfet-driver

I made this circuit for my tesla coil. It is a glorified slayer exciter. I based my circuit one the one shown [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-SSTC-Slayer-Exciter-On-Steroids/)

Both the coil supply and the control circuit supply come from an appropriately modified microwave oven transformer. The transformer core is grounded, and I noticed some sparks going from the 12V secondary to the core. These sparks only happen when the control circuit is activated and the secondary is generating high voltages. I suspect the diodes used to clip the input for the MOSFET driver are transferring the high voltage to the supply rail and thus to the transformer winding. Is there any way to prevent the MOSFET driver from frying and at the same time prevent high voltages in the supply rail? Can you suggest any improvements to the control circuit?

From what I gather high voltages in the mains system are very dangerous for appliances connected to the same network, so the transformer arcing is very bad news. I'd prefer not to switch it on until this is fixed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9GNVY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the transformer with a resistive ballast, the bridge rectifiers and the capacitors.

[image: transformer with resistive ballast, bridge rectifiers and capacitors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would eliminate the feedback loop from the transformer secondary (HV) and use a simple oscillator  (e.g. 555) to drive the '151 FET driver. Then you can fully take advantage of the isolation provided by T3.

I would also consider adding a snubbing diode across the primary of the tranformer to knock down the transients into the supply.